# Family of Sets Proof for Set Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a nonempty set. A ring of subsets of $A$ is a nonempty family $F$ of subsets of $A$ such that for all $S,T, \in F,$

(i) $S \cup T \in F$

(ii) $S \setminus T \in F$ (difference between the sets).

Prove that if $F$ is a ring of subsets of $A$, then for all $S, T \in F, S \cap T \in F.$

My attempt so far: 
From the first condition about the union, we have that 
$$S \cup T = \{ x: x \in S \; \textbf{or} \; x \in T \} \in F.$$
And from the second condition, 
$$S \setminus T  = \{ x: x \in S \; \textbf{and} \; x \not\in T \} \in F.$$

So then we have two cases:

I: 
$$\{ x : x \in S \} \in F$$
$$\{ x: x \in S \; \textbf{or} \; x \in T \} \in F.$$

II:
$$\{ x: x \in T \} \in F$$
$$\{ x: x \in S \; \textbf{and} \; x \not\in T \} \in F.$$

What i'm not sure about is how to transform these resulting facts into something about the intersection of arbitrary subsets of $F$.

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: You have to express $S \cap T$ using $\cup$ and $\setminus$ (maybe using only one of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Show that $S \cap T = S \setminus (S \setminus T)$.